# AsyncTask cancelada durante a execução não chama nenhum dos métodos pós-doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, async

Quando cancelo minha `AsyncTask` em execução, ela não atualiza a flag `mAsyncTaskEstaFinalizada`. Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Quando coloco *breakpoints* nos métodos `onCancelled()`, `onCancelled(resultado)` e `onPostExecute(resultado)`, o debugger não para em nenhum deles. Aguardo a asynctask atualizar a flag em um loop `while()` e o aplicativo entra em loop infinito. Isso pode acontecer? Já constatei no LogCat que nenhuma exceção está sendo lançada pela async task.

Estou testando no Android 4.0.3. E antes que alguém pergunte por que não estou checando o status da async task via `getStatus()`, é porque os estados fornecidos por esse método não atendem as minhas necessidades nesse caso.

```
class MinhaTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private boolean mAsyncTaskEstaFinalizada = false;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int progresso;
        ...
        publishProgress(progresso);

        while (false == isCancelled()) {
            ...
            publishProgress(progresso);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progresso) {
        exibeProgresso(progresso[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Void resultado) { // Chamado após cancel(boolean) quando o API level é 11 ou superior.
        onAsyncTaskCancelada();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() { // Chamado após cancel(boolean) quando o API level é 10 ou inferior.
        onAsyncTaskCancelada();
    }

    private void onAsyncTaskCancelada() {
        ...
        mAsyncTaskEstaFinalizada = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void resultado) {
        ...
        mAsyncTaskEstaFinalizada = true;
    }

    boolean asyncTaskEstaFinalizada() {
        return mAsyncTaskEstaFinalizada;
    }
}
```

Cancelando a execução:

```
MinhaTask minhaTask = new MinhaTask();
minhaTask.execute();

...

if (minhaTask != null && minhaTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
    minhaTask.cancel(false);
    while (false == minhaTask.asyncTaskEstaFinalizada()) {
        // Aguarda a asynctask terminar, porém está entrando em loop infinito!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O grande problema aqui é que o método `onCancelled`, assim como o método `onPostExecute`, são executados na `Thread` responsável por lidar com a UI, como diz a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Dessa forma, quando você faz:

> while (false == minhaTask.asyncTaskEstaFinalizada())

na `Thread` de UI, logo após o `minhaTask.cancel(false);`, você não deixa que o método termine, impedindo que `onCancelled` seja executado.

Para resolver isso rapidamente, remova esse

> while (false == minhaTask.asyncTaskEstaFinalizada())

do método, e faça, seja lá o que você gostaria de fazer, ou dentro do método `onAsyncTaskCancelada` ou dentro do método `onPostExecute`.

Comment: É verdade! Vacilo meu. Obrigado!